# Regular Expression \ ' " in php

Tags: php, regex

i searched here and in google.
maybe i haven't the right keywords.

What do i wrong?

```
$str="Hello \ ' \" World."; echo $str;
if (preg_match('/\\\'\"/',$str)) echo "<br>String has \ and \" and ' !";
```

EDIT (**solution**):

```
$str="Hello \ ' \" World."; echo $str;
if (preg_match( '/[*"]|[*\']|[*\\\]/',$str)) echo "<br>String has \ and \" and ' !";
```

Comment: In your case here, you're saying that the string literally has to be `\'"`

Comment: You're trying to match a backslash immediately followed by an apostrophe immediately followed by a double quote, and your string doesn't contain that.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces between `'` and `"`. Use this regex to make it work:

```
php> if (preg_match('/\\\' *"/',$str)) echo "<br>String has \ and \" and ' !";
<br>String has \ and " and ' !
```

Using this regex:

```
/\\\' *"/
     ^^
     |------------ Using " *" to allow 0 or more spaces here
```

Comment: A i see
is it rigth to write i it like this?:

'/[ *" ]|[ *\' ]|[ *\\ ]/'

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment. My answer was for your posted problem.

Comment: is there a " or a ' or a \ in the string. i think it works just fine. thank you :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** `/[\\\\'\"]+/`

```
$re = "/[\\\\'\"]+/";
$str = "Hello \ ' \" World.";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG2mG3/1)